# How can I allow GitHub contributors to add more contributors?

Tags: github

I need to add a lot of contributors to a private repository, it would be nice if a few other people could add them too. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A user with administrator privileges on the repository can add collaborators.  If you're using a team for this (e.g., in an organization), the maintainers of the team can add more members, as can organization owners.